# .scss file with emacs web-mode & colorization

Tags: emacs, sass

I'm using emacs with web modes and other stuff.

I'm updating my `.emacs` because I'm working with new tools. One of them is Sass. So, I wanna work with my  `*.scss` files without problem and in fact it works cool. But not perfect. Why?

My emacs has:
`(setq web-mode-enable-css-colorization t)`

And in my css I can see the colors. But in my scss I can't.

How can I activate css-colorization to scss files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it.

But it was with a work around. So, 
I installed the `rainbow-mode` from Elpa.

Plus, in my .emacs I added:
`(add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'rainbow-mode)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help.

There is a Major mode for editing SCSS files in Emacs:

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ScssMode